# Multiple websites admin folder from central codebase

Tags: php, linux, apache

I've written a small CMS system for my companies' customers.

It is supposed to run the 'admin' folder off the same codebase.

So if I have my codebase in the folder 'a.com/admin', then I could set up a new website on b.com, and when I go to 'b.com/admin', it should show the admin folder from 'a.com'.

Settings and configuration are handled by config files named after the HTTP_HOST.

I have tried Apache Alias, but couldn't get it working.

Then the solution would maybe be lndir to make shadow copies, but then we have to run that every time we create a new file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put your code in a common folder like common/admin. Then make your config files point to this directory.

Comment: That's not the way to go I believe.. Why can't I just say to the server, that when you go to b.com/admin, it should get the files from a.com/admin? Isn't there a way to do that?

Comment: You could do that but it's wrong. If the files are common then make them common.

Comment: If you really want to do it your way, take a look at apache mod rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Found out that I could set a custom per-domain httpd.conf:

```
Alias /admin "/home/xxxxx/domains/xxxx.com/public_html/admin"
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Apache for a while, but *maybe* this could work?

```
<VirtualHost>
  ...

  <Directory /admin>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/a.com/public_html/admin"
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```